# How do I use routes to navigate within the component of the Angular app?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, frontend, mean-stack

Can Angular be used to navigate between different elements of an Angular component? For example, if there is an about-us page, and I have a read-more button, such that when user clicks on read-more button, he should be navigated to read-more section which is present in the same about-us component (consider the section is somewhere at the bottom of page).

Is this possible?

If yes can anyone please help with some demos or pull request reference or any materials. I did not find any specific thing in Angular documentation section. Also, I'm new to this Angular thing and just trying to figure it out how can this be achieved. I assume that this has to do with paths and router module. But, I'm confused in what ways this can be done.

I'm using Angular 9

Comment: do you want to navigate up and down to specific location  in a page on click(via auto scroll something)

Comment: Hi @shashanksharma yes im trying to achieve the functionality that is user clicks the button he should be taken to selected section of same component. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using **ViewChild - scrollIntoView**.

Please find a example below:

```
<div #div1 id="div1">
  This is div 1
</div>

<div #div2 id="div2">
  This is div 2
</div>

<button (click)="goToDiv1()">Go to Div 1</button>
<button (click)="goToDiv2()">Go to Div 2</button>
```

Then in your ts file, define the function goToDiv1 and goToDiv2 as below :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `template.html        `
})
export class AppComponent {
    @ViewChild('div1') public div1:ElementRef;
    @ViewChild('div2') public div2:ElementRef;

    goToDiv1() {
            this.div1.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', inline: 'start' });
    }
   goToDiv2(){
        setImmediate(() => {
            this.div2.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', inline: 'start' });
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this meets your requirement.

Comment: You can use fragment `<a [routerLink]="['currentpath']" fragment="div1">Jump to div1</a>` via routerlink or via router, in your class `this.router.navigate( ['/whatever' ], {fragment: 'div1'})` Edit: this comment was meant to be in the question, sorry :)

Comment: Hi here while i'm trying to run your code it says that can not find SetImmediate. Is it that i have import it form any library? Thanks for your help sir and valuable time. :D

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do it by different forms:

1. Moving inside the same page with tools as scroll (there are some techniques related) or **[fragments](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview)**.
2. Building a nested routing and spliting your component in a module with different components.
3. Using something like **[tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview)** that can simulate navigation inside the same page.
4. The more basic way, using some vars to control with ng-if the parts that you want to see.

I think that you don not find anything because is more like you could structure your app instead of some specific angular behaviour.